# How to check if link is present on a page with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this link on my web page:

`<a href="https://mywebsite.com/terms-conditions-mywebsite" target="_blank">Terms and conditions</a>`

I want to use Jquery to check whether this specific link is present or not on the web page. I know how to check if text is present on a page, but am struggling a little with links. If it helps, it is only the `terms-conditions-mywebsite` bit that I need to use (as `mywebsite` changes depending on who is using the site).

The class is `footer` so I have tried `$('.footer:contains("terms-conditions")` but this doesn't seem to work. Any pointers would be appreciated, thanks so much :)

Edit: I need to check that the actual specific contents of this links is present, rather than the text 'Terms and conditions'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the value of *href* attribute. You can use [Attribute Contains Selector [name*=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) which *select elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing a given substring*:

The following should work:

```
if($('a[href*=terms-conditions]').length){
  //exist
}
```

**OR:** Check the link string directly

```
if($('a:contains("Terms and conditions")').length){
  //exist
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mamun - is there any way to check the actual contents of the link? E.g. that it contains the `terms-conditions-mywebsite` bit?

Comment: @Jordan1993, I have updated the answer, please check:)

Answer (score 1):

I would look at doing this with Javascript, as it's very straightforward and means you are not reliant on JQuery should you wish to remove JQuery from the site at a later date.

```
// get <a> elements
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

// loop through each <a>
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  // get each href
  var hrefs = links[i].getAttribute("href");
  // check href against the one you want
  if (hrefs == "https://www.google.com") {
    // check content of link
    console.log('link content:', links[i].innerHTML)
  }
}
```